# Spring Boot GET method with soft delete how to add another exception in service impl

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, soft-delete

I'm a beginner in Java and spring boot, and I implemented a User class with CRUD features. However now I need to add the feature that if exclusionFlag is True, the user can't be shown or modified, so I need to add the test if the flag is true before these CRUD actions.

The Code in the moment

UserServiceImpl.java

```
@Override
    public UserResponse getAllUsers(int pageNo, int pageSize, String sortBy, String sortDir) {

        Sort sort = sortDir.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name()) ? Sort.by(sortBy).ascending()
                : Sort.by(sortBy).descending();

        Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(pageNo, pageSize, sort);
        Page<User> users = userRepository.findAll(pageable);
        List<User> listOfUsers = users.getContent();
        List<UserDto> content= listOfUsers.stream().map(user -> mapToDTO(user)).collect(Collectors.toList());

        UserResponse userResponse = new UserResponse();
        userResponse.setContent(content);
        userResponse.setPageNo(users.getNumber());
        userResponse.setPageSize(users.getSize());
        userResponse.setTotalElements(users.getTotalElements());
        userResponse.setTotalPages(users.getTotalPages());
        userResponse.setLast(users.isLast());
        return userResponse;
    }
 @Override
    public UserDto getUserById(long id) {
        User user = userRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));
      //any other addition like:
      //User user = userRepository.filterByExclusionFlag(true).orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("User not found"));
      //results in errors like the function can't throw exception and I added the filterByExclusionFlag in UserRepository. Have no idea how to add this feature on UserService
        return mapToDTO(user);
    }
```

Comment: Can you please add the logs of the error? Or is it a compile time error?

Comment: Which Spring Data is that? Spring Data JPA or something else?

Comment: It's better to copy the full code and the error log here. Additionally, I don't know what inhibitor method exactly you want, but it should be written the in the repository. For example, if you want to check the existence of something it is accessible via `existsBy` or if you want check the boolean result `IsFalse` may help you.

Comment: The best approach is to create a new column in the user's table as exclusion_flag and using constructor DTO projection instead of inbuilt findById with @Query having exlusionFlag as value false.Save each user with default value for Flag as false. Your sample query will be like this : select <needed columns> from User where exclusion_flag =false;

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to create a new column in the user's table as exclusion_flag and using constructor DTO projection instead of inbuilt findById with @Query having exlusionFlag as value false.
Save each user with default value for Flag as false. Your sample query will be like this : `select needed columns from User where exclusion_flag =false` .
And for your modification API (PUT) , ask the client to pass the value fetched from the above (GET) API to pass in the request.The flag passed in the request param helps you to identify if user can be modified or not.